# Wierd Memory Full Error - AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, installation, easy-install

```
df -ih
 Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
 /dev/xvda1       512K   45K  468K    9% /
 udev             205K   389  205K    1% /dev
 tmpfs            207K   271  207K    1% /run
 none             207K     4  207K    1% /run/lock
 none             207K     1  207K    1% /run/shm
 overflow         207K    14  207K    1% /tmp
 /dev/xvdf        1.9M   354  1.9M    1% /db
df -ah
 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/xvda1      8.0G  3.6G  4.0G  48% /
 proc               0     0     0    - /proc
 sysfs              0     0     0    - /sys
 none               0     0     0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
 none               0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
 none               0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
 udev            819M  8.0K  819M   1% /dev
 devpts             0     0     0    - /dev/pts
 tmpfs           331M  184K  331M   1% /run
 none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
 none            827M     0  827M   0% /run/shm
 overflow        1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /tmp
 /dev/xvdf        30G   14G   16G  48% /db
 /db/etc/mysql    30G   14G   16G  48% /etc/mysql
 /db/lib/mysql    30G   14G   16G  48% /var/lib/mysql
 /db/log/mysql    30G   14G   16G  48% /var/log/mysql
sudo easy_install nltk
 Searching for nltk
 Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/nltk/
 Reading http://nltk.org/
 Reading http://www.nltk.org/
 Reading http://www.nltk.org/download
 Reading http://nltk.sf.net/
 Best match: nltk 2.0.3
 Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/nltk/nltk-2.0.3.zip#md5=88bb51626ceb7eee58be64b73d43cafc
 error: No space left on device
```

Where is the problem? It shows I have space on all partitions. It shows that my inodes are also not full. I am not able to install. I have tried sudo apt-get autoremove as well. Thanks a ton

Comment: 1M on /tmp might not be enough for the installer to run properly. You could use `strace` to find out what device does not have enough space left.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Bart Friederichs in comments,

/tmp was the problem. So, downloaded the installation zip folder and installed it not from /tmp.